# PHP DOM and swaping IPS

Tags: php, dom

I was wondering is there a way to use PHP DOM classes(currently using http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ and doesn't seem to support it) and switch between server ips?

I need equivalent of 'CURLOPT_INTERFACE' that is used for curl, but for DOM in this case, as I don't want to use my account's shared IP, I want to use it's dedicated IP

Comment: The DOM is a representation of XML documents, and totally unrelated to Internet Protocol Addresses as well as Intrusion Prevention Systems, so I can't find any sense in your question. Could you elaborate, for example by giving an example XML document?

Comment: I need equivalent of 'CURLOPT_INTERFACE' that is used for curl, but for DOM in this case, as I don't want to use my account's shared IP, I want to use it's dedicated IP

Comment: We're getting closer, but the only DOM functionality related to network access is [DOM Load/Save](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-LS/load-save.html), and it doesn't specify anything about interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply download the XML or HTML document with curl with the desired options (and `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`), and *then* parse it with your preferred DOM implementation, like this:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, 'eth0');
$content = curl_exec($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($content);
echo 'Root node is ' . $doc->documentElement->tagName . '!';
```

Comment: That sounds like it could work, how would I request the document to be returned as xml? Thanks!

Comment: @Saulius Antanavicius Added an example.

Comment: not sure how, but you managed to do what I needed to do with DOM, my curl must of stopped JS execution or something, as it just didnt return the data that was loaded in via JS, Thank you!

Comment: Second line from the end should be `$doc->loadXML($content);` if your content is xml. Not much of a difference, but xml should always be well-formed, and this function will tell you, if it's not. Additional info at [http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Comment: @Andrius Virbičianskas Yup. Unfortunately, `example.com` serves only HTML. Amended the answer.